# Capturing optional part of URL with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

While writing an API service for my site, I realized that `String.split()` won't do it much longer, and decided to try my luck with regular expressions. I have almost done it but I can't find the last bit. Here is what I want to do:

The URL represents a function call:

```
/api/SECTION/FUNCTION/[PARAMS]
```

This last part, including the slash, is optional. Some functions display a JSON reply without having to receive any arguments. Example: `/api/sounds/getAllSoundpacks` prints a list of available sound packs. Though,  `/api/sounds/getPack/8Bit` prints the detailed information.

Here is the expression I have tried:

```
req.url.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)\/?(.*)/);
```

What am I missing to make the last part optional - or capture it in whole?

Comment: Why isn't String.split() not useful anymore?

Comment: @jeff: If there is another / in the last part, then it gets cut off. I can't tell `.split()` to stop splitting after a certain amount - if I do, the rest will go into the void. That is why I reached for regex.

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Using split, just test if the array index has a value i.e. if( str[4] !== '') {.... do your stuff }

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I am using connect, so /api is handled, and the actual part I want to handle is either: /sounds/getAll or /sounds/get/Something. Output is either: ["sounds","getAll"] or ["sounds", "get", "Something"]

Answer (score 0):

This will capture everything after FUNCTION/ in your URL, independent of the appearance of any further / after FUNCTION/:

```
FUNCTION\/(.+)$
```

The RegExp will not match if there is no part after FUNCTION.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work by making last slash and part after optional:

```
/^\/[^/]*\/[^/]*(?:\/.*)?$/
```

This matches all of these strings:

```
/api/SECTION/FUNCTION/abc
/api/SECTION
/api/SECTION/
/api/SECTION/FUNCTION
```

Comment: Yes I see that too but isn't that what you expected? You can see it matched both `/sounds/getAll/Packs` and `/sounds/getAll/`. If this is not what you wanted then please clarify requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `/(.*)/(.*)/?(.*)` was almost correct, it's just a bit too short - it allows 2 or 3 slashes, but you want to accept anything with 3 or 4 slashes. And if you want to capture the last (optional) slash AND any text behind it as a whole, you simply need to create a group around that section and make it optional:

```
/.*/.*/.*(?:/.+)?
```

should do the trick.

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/tI3mH6/2) (The pattern looks different because multiline mode is enabled, but it still works. It's also a little "better" because it won't match garbage like "///".)